# Free/libre bookkeeping for freelancer in Germany

Tags: linux, open-source, finance

I’m looking for a bookkeeping solution for freelancers in Germany. The goal is to replace various spreadsheets.

It must be FLOSS.
It must run on GNU/Linux (can be a self-hosted web app or a desktop client with GUI).
It must be actively maintained.

What I need:

- No double-entry bookkeeping! I only need the most simple kind: just let me track expenses and revenues, based on incoming and outgoing invoices.
- For each invoice, let me record data (like the bill number, the date, the net sum, the gross sum, the tax) and let me attach it as PDF.
- Let me track which invoices were paid, and when.
- Output the data necessary for filling out all the required forms on [ELSTER](https://www.elster.de/eportal/start) (bonus points if the solution can submit some forms itself), e.g.:

  - the [*Umsatzsteuer-Voranmeldung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umsatzsteuer-Voranmeldung_(Deutschland)),
  - the *Umsatzsteuererklärung*,
  - the [*Einkommensteuererklärung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einkommensteuererkl%C3%A4rung) with the [*Anlage EÜR* (*Einnahmenüberschussrechnung*)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einnahmen%C3%BCberschussrechnung) and the [*Anlage S* (*Einkünfte aus selbständiger Arbeit*)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eink%C3%BCnfte_aus_selbst%C3%A4ndiger_Arbeit_(Deutschland)).

Comment: did you find something suitable?